# Making a noise function without binary operators?

Tags: random, lua, noise

Is there any possible way to make pseudorandom numbers without any binary operators? Being that this is a 3D map, I'm trying to make it as a function of X and Y but hopefully include a randomseed somewhere in their so it won't be the same every time. I know you can make a noise function like this with binary operators :

```c
double PerlinNoise::Noise(int x, int y) const
{
    int n = x + y * 57;
    n = (n << 13) ^ n;
    int t = (n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff;
    return 1.0 - double(t) * 0.931322574615478515625e-9;/// 1073741824.0);
}
```

But being that I'm using lua instead of C++, I can't use any binary operators. I've tried many different things yet none of them work. ***Help?***

Comment: Sure. Use trinary operators instead. If you restrict it to unary, though... $x_{n+1} = \sin(\exp(x_n))$ might produce good results.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just now going into algebra 2. What does xn+1 mean/do?

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is that the $n^\hbox{th}$ psuedorandom number be $\sin(\exp(\hbox{the }n - 1\hbox{th psuedorandom number}))$. Note that $\exp(x)=e^x$. Another good one would have the $n^\hbox{th}$ psuedorandom number be $sin(exp(n))$.

Comment: Wait... By binary do you mean accepts 2 values or do you mean things like xor and binary shifts?

Comment: I mean I'm using lua so I don't have any binary operators at hand. Also I was talking about the sub n+1. Where it's lower than it?

Comment: @No No: We are generating the numbers in order.  The first number we produce is called $x_1$, the second number we produce is called $x_2$, the third is called $x_3$, and so on. So the $n$th number is called $x_n$, and the $(n+1)$th is called $x_{n+1}$.  The formula of @gereeter means that in particular, $x_8=\sin(\exp(x_7))$, $x_{21}=\sin(\exp(x_{20}))$, and so on. If you prefer, you could call the first number $f(1)$, the second number produced $f(2)$, and so on. Then the formula would read $f(n+1)=\sin(\exp(f(n)))$.

Comment: @No No: I don't know Lua. But in generic code, one might write $$\text{next_number}=\sin(\exp(\text{current_number})).$$

Comment: Well that makes since. Yet what I really want is to be able to generate it without having to save anything as of just having a function of x and y. This way I can easily delete the areas not around the player and not waste any memory because the number will be the same every time, and also allow me to make endless terrain. I tried using trinary operators like gereeter said, yet they don't come out looking random at all. ( mostly because of my math yet still. )

Comment: I thought that you meant a function that only accepted 1 value, which prompted my earlier answers. However, for something like Lua, I'd use [Perlin Noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) on some combination of some sine functions, exponentials, and sawtooth functions (like functions that take the fractional part of a value). Play around! If you stick functions in everywhere, you'll either get a neat mathematical identity or very weird randomness.

Comment: Use Math.random, which is apparently a lua function. Don't "play around", you might get into the habit of doing this when it actually matters.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus math.random() does basically the same thing as @gereeter 's first example, which is not what I'm wanting.

Comment: I think it would help if you added an example of what you mean by a noise function *with* "binary operators". That would make it clearer what you are looking for.

Comment: I believe an example with "binary operators" can be found on my previous link about Perlin Noise. `function IntNoise(32-bit integer: x)
    x = (x<<13) ^ x;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);
  end IntNoise function`. That article is very informative about Perlin Noise, which I think is the solution in this case.

Comment: @Rahul Narain I did it. Also @gereeter 's example is the one I've seen many times and had also added at almost the same time he posted ironically.

Comment: Is `sin(e^x)` noisy enough? Try graphing it. For negative x it is really boring, so if you want bidirectional, you might have to do something like `sin(e^x)+sin(e^(-x))+sin(e^(x+5))+sin(e^(-x-5))`. _Very_ noisy.

Comment: when I try `math.fmod(math.exp(x),math.cos(y))` it works okish except then it makes half of the map completely flat. ( No no on stackoverflow, I woulda used this on the math one too except it wouldn't let me log on with this account )

Answer (score 3):

For bit operators (I guess that is what you mean by "binary"), have a look at [Bitwise Operators Wiki page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators), which contains a list of modules you can use, like [Lua BitOp](http://bitop.luajit.org/) and [bitlib](http://luaforge.net/projects/bitlib).

If you do not want to implement it by yourself, have a look at the module [lua-noise](https://github.com/agladysh/lua-noise/), which contains an implementation of Perlin noise. Note that it is a work-in-progress C module.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, Matt Zucker's [FAQ on Perlin noise](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html) only uses arithmetic operators to describe/implement it. It only mentions bitwise operators as an optimization trick.

You should implement both ways and test them with the same language/runtime, to get an idea of the speed difference.

Answer (score 1):

In the above routine, there are not any bit-wise operators that aren't easily converted to arithmetic operations.

The << 13 becomes * 8192

The & 0x7FFFFFFF becomes a mod of 2^31.

As long as overflow isn't an issue, this should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be pretty slow, but you could simulate these with division and multiplication, I believe.